# Get notification before deleting the file

Tags: java, android

I want to save the deleted files like Dumpster. I am using the fileobserver, but its not working . Its notifying after the file deletion.

```
FileObserver Observer = null; 
Observer = new FileObserver(observepath) 
{
    @Override public void onEvent(int event, String path) 
   {
        if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event)!=0 || (FileObserver.DELETE_SELF & event)!=0) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   }
}
```

Here the toast message is coming after the file deletion i checked this by debug mode by putting break point there. And i used "File.delete()" to delete the file. Now my question is after invoking the file.delete() is it possible to notify ?

Comment: What you have tried? Show us a code-snippet. I can't see a question here..

Comment: To help with your code we need to see it :-)

Comment: FileObserver Observer = null;
Observer = new FileObserver(observepath){ 
   @Override
   public void onEvent(int event, String path) 
   {
      if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event)!=0 || (FileObserver.DELETE_SELF & event)!=0) 
         {Toast.maketext();}}

Comment: Edit your original post and format it as code, please.

Comment: it's system event. If you haven't deleted file, how can you receive the notification? If you wanna do something before delete, you should do it by your code.

Comment: after deleting this fileobserver notifying that the file was deleted.I am asking is it possible to notify before delete ?

Comment: Not with a `FileObserver`, see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) for supported events

Comment: no. But the delete event can be triggered by other event, like onClick of delete button. You can save file in onClick